# Need help figuring out a pattern question

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

my cousin asked for help on this math problem and the answer is apparently 6 but i can't find a coherent pattern that fits all of the triangles. I included an image of the question.

[image]

Comment: Does the blue tape/highlighter have anything to do with the question? Just making sure.

Comment: it was just my cousin's notes ! not part of the question but someone else already answered :)

Answer (score 1):

The missing no is 6. Sum of numbers in each horizontal layer is 36.

Comment: thank you ! i found that out after i stopped focusing on the triangles 

Answer (score 0):

The number is $n=66$. The sum of all alternating sums of  the rows should equal zero. So we need
$$
36+(30-n)-8+8=0,
$$
which says that $n=66$.
For example, the last row has alternating sum $$4-7+5-4+5-3+8=8$$